# The loaction.reload(true) causes force get - how to do this when setting .src

Tags: javascript

I am currently setting the `.src` of an `iframe` to a page. However after I load it, I am having to do `.reload(true)` as if I don't, the cached version is showing.

I looked into `location.assign` and `location.replace` however they do not allow me the `forceGet` argument, as does `reload`. Is there anyway to load page with `forceGet` like behavior?

`froceGet` is explained as:

> By default, the reload() method reloads the page from the cache, but you can force it to reload the page from the server by setting the forceGet parameter to true: location.reload(true).

Source here - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: Proper caching headers?

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder but I am making a browse addon, so I cannot modify the server headers. I just can set location of iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add a query string to the url

**edit1** by adding query string to the url the browser understand that there were a change that justify a reload of a page and then the page is been reloaded

Comment: While it most likely will work, you should explain why. A `try to add ...` only  answer that does not explain anything is not helpful. Even if it will help the OP other people reading the question might not understand why it will work.

Comment: Adding/changing a query string does not really tell the browser that there was a change on request resource, it actually results in a different URL, so the browser has to request it if it is not in cache. Because it is a different URL, that data that is returned might also be different (but in most situations it might work well, if a parameter was chosen that normally is not used.)

Comment: Thanks very much Zamboney and @t.niese this worked! However it's a work around no? What if the page doesn't accept extra query string parameters? Is this a limitation of javascript? They don't have a feature to load a page with `forceGet` like `location.reload`?

Comment: if you have access to the parent and the child pages you can use a postmessage event to reload the page form the parent.

Comment: Thanks Zamboney that's a good idea. I was just trying to avoid two page loads as it is making the user experience janky. I'm going with the query string for now :)